# VoiceOver Finds "Empty Line"s on both sides of a UITextView

Tags: ios, uitextview, voiceover

I have a table view where the cells each contain only a UITextView, set up as such:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil];
// Declare and set text & frame
...
UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
textView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
textView.editable = NO;
textView.font = font;
textView.scrollEnabled = NO;
textView.text = text;
[cell.contentView addSubview:textView];
```

When I test with VoiceOver on, I can find two places that are just small empty items, for which VoiceOver says "empty line", on the left and right edges of the text in the text view.  If I have a multi-line string, e.g. `@"multiple\nlines"`, then there is an "empty line" at the right edge of the first line and another at the left edge of the second line.  I can't find "empty line"s to the left of the first line or the right of the second line, but for all I know they are just hard to find.

Why does VoiceOver find these "empty line"s?  How do I get rid of them?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a workaround for [this bug](http://openradar.io/12430939) that we came up with today.

Subclass UITextView and override:

```
- (BOOL)isAccessibilityElement {
    return NO;
}
```

Returning `NO` opts out of VoiceOver. Then, make a container add the textview to it and set a custom accessibilityLabel on the container view:

```
containerView.accessibilityLabel = textview.text
```

This obviously won't work for some cases (I haven't looked into editing very much), but it at least gets you to a place where the text view doesn't display the behavior in question.

Comment: If you are gonna go through the trouble of embedding it within a container, just setting the container as an accessibility element and its `navigationStyle` to `Combined` should be enough to resolve the issue (with the label, of course).

Comment: I think textView.accessibilityTraits = UIAccessibilityTraitStaticText would also work, if this is read-only text.